# Some problem about regular language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Let's say $\alpha$ is *simple* word if it couldn't be represented as $\beta^{n}$($n$ times concatenation of $\beta$), where $\beta \ne \alpha$

Consider two sets: $p_{N}(L) = \{\alpha^{n} | \alpha \in L ; n \in N\}$ and $SL = \{ \alpha | \alpha$ - simple word, $\alpha^{n} \in L; n \ge 1 \}$, where $N \subset \mathbb{N}$.

Prove that $p_{N}(L)$ is regular language if and only if $SL$ is finite.

As I said in comment , possibly we could make a contradiction about finiteness of $SL$, when $p_{N}(L)$ is regular.
For example , we could construct a word , which doesn't apply $p_{N}(L)$.

Comment: 1. What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  2. I don't understand your notation.  What does $\alpha - simple$ mean?

Comment: 3. The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: @D.W. I gave definition of simple word. So $SL$ is set of all simple words , which power lies on $L$.

Comment: @D.W. I suppose that $p(L)$ is regular language and assumed that $SL$ is infinite , then I tried to construct a word , which lies on $SL$ and don't constructs at $p(L)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the paper *Roots and Powers of Regular Languages* by Horváth, Leupold and Lischke (DLT 2002, LNCS 2450, doi [10.1007/3-540-45005-X_19](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-45005-X_19)) which states in the abstract:

> For a set $H$ of natural numbers, the $H$-power of a language $L$ is the set of all words $p^k$ where $p \in L$ and $k \in H$. The root of $L$ is the set of all primitive words $p$ such that $p^n$ belongs to $L$ for some $n \ge 1$. There is a strong connection between the root and the powers of a regular language $L$ namely, the $H$-power of $L$ for an arbitrary finite set $H$ with $0, 1, 2 \notin H$ is regular if and only if the root of $L$ is finite.

Note the special provision for the numbers $0,1,2$.